# Syntax error at expression level in Informatica

Tags: sql, oracle, expression, informatica

I have a critical logic which need to be implemented , but not getting how do i write the `if logic` at expression level in Informatica

**My logic :**

```
if (empid =='SBCS'):
then

    empcd = v_employee_code_number

elif empcal <> depcal and empid in ('SSC','HSC'):
then
 
    empcd = (emp_sal/avgsal) * empad

elif empcal <> depcal and empid not in ('SSC','HSC'):
then
    
    empcd = emp_del

else:
    
   empcd = emp_dev
```

I need to write the above logic at expression level in Informatica and even SQL query ?

I have tried below logic. It is throwing syntax error in expression

```
iif( empid =='SBCS',v_employee_code_number,iif(empcal <> depcal and empid in ('SSC','HSC')),(emp_sal/avgsal) * empad, empcal <> depcal and empid not in ('SSC','HSC'), emp_del,emp_dev)
```

The above need to write in SQL but not getting how to write it

Comment: Have a look at the SQL Reference guide. "==" is not valid syntax in oracle.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, the `==` is not a valid syntax. Also `in` is not supported. I've rewritten your iif statement as follows (please verify!)

```
iif( empid ='SBCS',
    v_employee_code_number,
    iif(empcal <> depcal and (empid = 'SSC' or empid = 'HSC'),
        (emp_sal/avgsal) * empad, 
        iif(empcal <> depcal and empid <> 'SSC' and empid <> 'HSC',
        emp_del,
        emp_dev)
    )
)
```

But nested `IIF` is really hard to read, so better yet go with `DECODE` function (please refer [the docs for details](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-2/transformation-language-reference/functions/decode.html)). This would look then like:

```
DECODE(TRUE,
    empid ='SBCS', v_employee_code_number,
    empcal <> depcal and (empid = 'SSC' or empid = 'HSC'), (emp_sal/avgsal) * empad,
    empcal <> depcal and empid <> 'SSC' and empid <> 'HSC', emp_del,
    emp_dev
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard SQL `case` expression (which will work in Oracle too) for your logic is:

```sql
empcd := case
  when empid = 'SBCS'
    then v_employee_code_number
  when empcal != depcal and empid in ('SSC','HSC')
    then (emp_sal/avgsal) * empad
  when empcal != depcal and empid not in ('SSC','HSC')
    then emp_del
  else emp_dev
end
```