# Re-write the if logic to DECODE statement in Informatica

Tags: expression, informatica

I have logic which i need to convert it to decode statement

**My logic is below :**

```
if emptr =='SBCS':

   empcd=empvar

else:

    if empcal <> depcal and empid in ('SSC','HSC'):

            empcd = (emp_sal/avgsal) * empad

    elif empcal <> depcal and empid not in ('SSC','HSC'):

            empcd = emp_del

    else:
            empcd = emp_dev
```

**Tried myself to write the logic in expression**

```
IIF ( emptr ='SBCS' , empvar , IIF(empcal <> depcal,IIF(empcal <> depcal and empid in ('SSC','HSC'),(emp_sal/avgsal) * empad,emp_del),emp_dev))
```

**I have written DECODE logic , but not sure right or wrong**

```
DECODE(TRUE,
    empid ='SBCS', empvar,
    empcal <> depcal and (empid = 'SSC' or empid = 'HSC'), (emp_sal/avgsal) * empad,
    empcal <> depcal and (empid <> 'SSC' or empid <> 'HSC'), emp_del,
    emp_dev
)
```

Feel free to share your logic if the `DECODE` logic is not right

Comment: @Maciejg  : Can you share your helping hands .. to format the logic to DECODE statement

Comment: @Marek Grzenkowicz : Can you share your helping hands .. to format the logic to DECODE statement

Comment: @arturro : Can you share your helping hands .. to format the logic to DECODE statement

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to below expression. Pls remove comments (`--comments`) if needed.

```
iif (emptr ='SBCS', empvar,
   iif( -- first else if part
        empcal <> depcal and IN (empid, 'SSC','HSC'), (emp_sal/avgsal) * empad,
        iif ( --second elif   
             empcal <> depcal and NOT IN (empid, 'SSC','HSC') , emp_del,
             emp_dev -- last else 
             )
       )
    )
```

I can see your expression and can see some issue with 3rd or condition. in case of NOT IN, or doesnt work. I changed your decode so you can use code below but pls check it before using it.

```
DECODE(TRUE,
    empid ='SBCS', empvar,
    empcal <> depcal and (empid = 'SSC' or empid = 'HSC'), (emp_sal/avgsal) * empad,
    empcal <> depcal and (empid <> 'SSC' and empid <> 'HSC'), emp_del,
    emp_dev
)
```

Comment: Can you check it once again the second condition seems like missing with `comma (,)`. I am not sure can you re check

Comment: got it, corrected it now. could you pls check again?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've already answered [this exact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70210870/syntax-error-at-expression-level-in-informatica/70214920#70214920) question [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70214920/2834065). Was there anything wrong with the below code I provided?

```
DECODE(TRUE,
    empid ='SBCS', v_employee_code_number,
    empcal <> depcal and (empid = 'SSC' or empid = 'HSC'), (emp_sal/avgsal) * empad,
    empcal <> depcal and empid <> 'SSC' and empid <> 'HSC', emp_del,
    emp_dev
)
```

Comment: little bit confusion I am having for this  : `empid not in ('SSC','HSC')`  it should be `empid <> 'SSC' OR  empid <> 'HSC' `. Can you justify  or it should be AND

Comment: Think about it. `empid not in ('SSC','HSC')` means exactly that empid must not be SSC and must not be HSC. Now it means it has to be different than SSC AND different than HSC.
Now check your suggested condition `empid <> 'SSC' OR  empid <> 'HSC'`: 
if `empid='SSC'` the above condition is TRUE, as it is different than `HSC` :)